# C99: Dynamic dispatch in a static library

Tags: c, static-libraries, c99

Say I am developing a Math library and I want it to be such that it will detect whether or not user's machine support SSE (and which version) and based on that, separate internal functions will be called for the same API function. I can think of three ways to implement that:

1. Have **global** function pointers in the library and let user call mathInit() in their source. When they do, figure out the hardware details and assign the function pointers to different functions.
2. Same, except instead of having global function pointers, put them in a **struct** which is returned by mathInit(). This way, user will have to call math.vec3Add(...) or similar.
3. Same as 1, but instead of having global pointers, make mathInit() a **macro** so that the function pointers will have local scope in user's main() function (and require mathInit() to be called from main()). It will be in a header, of course.

Is any of these methods preferable? Is there some other, better way?

Comment: 3 is simply unacceptable, no ifs or buts here.

Comment: @n.m. I haven't worked with function pointers much before, so all three seemed pretty inelegant. Hence, the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely opinion-based, IMHO.

And my opinion is, a math library should expose the least possible amount of details about its internal workings and should not require tricky function pointers or data structures or even macros to work with to the user code, if possible.

I'd go with (1) and assume you would completely hide the function pointers in your library, i.e. call them through an indirection in library code.

(3) is definitely the worst option, because it puts restrictions on the user code that are not directly obvious. It might also create non-obvious problems/observations when debugging user code.

(2) Is a pretty uncommon way to present a library and requires at least intermediate C fluency, and might put off non-expert C users.

You could also expose a `hasSSE`function along with SSE and non-SSE functions and leave the decision what to use to the user code. Not sure that would have any benefits over (1), though.

Comment: Do you see any other problem in (2) except for unconventional interface for a C library? I was thinking of avoiding globals since I might decide to write a hot loadable shared library using this in the future and globals might mess with that (not sure).

Comment: I don't see any technical problems with variables in a shared library - They wouldn't need to be *global* to the application anyhow. You could easily make them `static` to their indirection in the library. And "unconventional interface" - Remember especially maths functions are often used by non-professional programmers. I would avoid that at any cost.

Comment: The library will mostly be used internally for my own engine. And regarding globals in shared libraries: http://nullprogram.com/blog/2014/12/23/  [third paragraph]

Comment: @NamanDixit I just pointed out the function pointers don't need to be *global* in your library - So most of what's written there doesn't apply (It does apply in the linked form only to Windows anyhow - Don't know what your platform is.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be compiling a separate unit for each instruction set (e.g. Xnosse.o Xsse3.o Xsse4.o, etc.) and use an automatic dispatcher for those. The user needs to get the best performance for his PC, and not care about the inside detailing.

Since you wrote your code runs in a library, you can make the dispatch decision on load time automatically by using an init function that will be called on library load. You can also make this decision run only the firsts time a function is actually called, this is for lazy binding.

Here is a code example (gcc only!)

Compilation units:

```
//Xnosse.c
void do_some_math_stuff_no_sse(int x, int y)
{
    ...do some sophisticated math stuff with no sse support
}
void do_some_other_math_stuff_no_sse(int x, int y)
{
    ...do some other sophisticated math stuff with no sse support
}

//Xsse3.c
void do_some_math_stuff_sse3(int x, int y)
{
    ...do some sophisticated math stuff with sse3 support
}
void do_some_other_math_stuff_sse3(int x, int y)
{
    ...do some other sophisticated math stuff with sse3 support
}

//Xsse4.c
void do_some_math_stuff_sse4(int x, int y)
{
    ...do some sophisticated math stuff with sse4 support
}
void do_some_other_math_stuff_sse4(int x, int y)
{
    ...do some other sophisticated math stuff with sse4 support
}
```

Now to the library:

```
//my_math.h
/* Following definitions are in my_math.c */
extern void (*do_some_math_stuff)(int x, int, y);
extern void (*do_some_other_math_stuff)(int x, int y);

//my_math.c
void not_set(int x, int y)
{
    // If you don't want to use the constructor for any reason,
    // say you want lazy binding, this will do the trick as our
    // functions do_math_stuff and do_other_math_stuff are initialized
    // to this one
    setup();
}

void (*do_some_math_stuff)(int x, int, y) = not_set;
void (*do_some_other_math_stuff)(int x, int y) = not_set;

int detect_sse()
{
    ..Do runtime detection of sse version
}

/* The following function will be called when your library loads */
void __attribute__ ((constructor)) setup(void) 
{
    if (detect_sse() == 0)
    {
        do_some_math_stuff = do_some_math_stuff_no_sse;
        do_some_other_math_stuff = do_some_other_math_stuff_no_sse;
    }
else if (detect_sse() == 3)
    {
        do_some_math_stuff = do_some_math_stuff_sse3;
        do_some_other_math_stuff = do_some_other_math_stuff_sse3;
    }
else if (detect_sse() == 4)
    {
        do_some_math_stuff = do_some_math_stuff_sse4;
        do_some_other_math_stuff = do_some_other_math_stuff_sse4;
    }
}
```

If you want lazy binding, remove constructor decorater from setup and compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libmy_math.so my_math.c Xnosse.c Xsse3.c Xsse4.c
```

If you want the dynamic dispatcher to run when the library loads use the following additional parameters to gcc:

```
gcc -Wall -shared -Wl,-init,setup -fPIC -o libmy_math.so my_math.c Xnosse.c Xsse3.c Xsse4.c
```

Comment: This is basically using globals, only user doesn't has to call mathInit(); right? I don't have a problem with mathInit, the engine will have entire initialization subsystem.My question is that whether using global function pointers is the right choice?

Comment: Using global function pointers are fine. Using functions that call these function pointers is even better. In any case the only thing you should care about is what you expose to the user - best approach for that is functions